# Capturing the user's sound card output in a Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, audio-streaming, java-web-start, javasound

I'm looking for a way to capture the sound card output of users and stream it to a red5 server via RTMP in real time.

Using audio redirecting, e.g. with the Windows Stereo Mix is not an option, as it is pretty difficult to configure and it doesn't work consistently across configurations and Windows versions.

I'm open for all sorts of solution possibilities in this direction - maybe even with JNI/JNA?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: What's your configuration difficulty with using the Windows audio mix?

Comment: I agree with @Neil Coffey - the stereo mix option does work consistently across all modern versions on windows. Since Vista the device is typically disabled by default but there are plenty of tutorials out there to correct that - http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/39532/how-to-enable-stereo-mix-in-windows-7-to-record-audio/

Comment: I find it too difficult for the user. And even in our own office we have found a configuration in which the Stereo Mix doesn't work (XP). The feature is crucial for our app.

Comment: It strikes me that the problem you're trying to solve is "users can bugger up the configuration of their machine", and theere's not really a solution to this. On the machine you've seen where the Windows Stereo Mix doesn't appear to be working, I would invest at least a little bit of time in finding out what the configuration problem actually is and how your app can detect and alert users to it, rather than jumping to more radical (and possibly non-working) solutions such as writing a sound driver...!

Comment: Stereo mix doesn't appear on Windows 7 or Vista, even on sound cards where it is traditionally supported, like Creative cards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - there is definitely no native way in Java to capture the sound card output out of the browser. It is possible to use the Java Native Interface to write platform-specific code to intercept the line and pass the raw audio data to the applet to further process it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are open to using JNI/JNA why not access the sound driver via C++ or C, that would much be easier because anyway you are going to write the interface in Java but their implementation would be in C++ or C.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think this would help. As far as I'm aware, there's no "secret" output that a sound driver can get that you don't get in Java by capturing the Windows stereo mix. In other words, if the user has managed to configure their machine so that nothing comes out of the Windows stereo mix, a multiplexing sound driver won't capture anything either. I guess there's no harm in the poster researching this more, though.

Answer (score 0):

See [Capturing Audio](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html) in the Java Tutorial.

An applet will need to be digitally signed as well as trusted by the end user, before it will be possible to intercept the data in the sound lines.

If no software or hardware 'audio loop-back' is enabled, it might fail completely (even in a fully trusted applet).

Comment: As I said in the question, I don't want to capture a sound card input signal (or loop back device), but the _output_ of the sound card.

Comment: Yes, I understand that from your original question.  What is your point?  BTW - an applet can make sounds when in a sand-box, but to **intercept the data in the sound lines** (e.g. read the **output**) you will need a signed applet.

Comment: @Andrew -- have you actually tried this. I have a feeling it's not true. (The documentation says you need a signed Applet, but at least in some versions of the Java plugin this doesn't appear to be true.)

Comment: @Neil Which versions of the plug-in?  Given that a sand-boxed applet can send data back to it's home server, that would mean that an applet could 'listen in' on the end user and forward the sound data to the supplier of the site/applet without the user's specific knowledge.  That seems like a **huge** security bug to me.

Comment: @Neil: And to answer your specific question, no I have not actually tried recording in an applet, only a JWS application.

Comment: @Andrew -- Have just done a bit more testing and it looks like you can open lines without exception, but read() always returns zero bytes. So I guess this is good from a security point of view, but something to bear in mind from an application design point of view.

Answer (score 0):

This is not as trivial, as it might seem.

What you need to do [ part 1 - creating a place to store the info ]:

- describe the server, where to store the file. (for example: Google App Engine)
- describe how you want to store the file. (for example: datastore)
- describe how important is the integrity of the data. (for example: it's easier to upload a file, with existing upload api, then to stream data. Example Apache FileUpload)

Lets say you have maximum size of 1 mb file, (example .ogg) audio file, that you want to upload to a server database. If you are going to create a automation uploader, you might aswell create a webpage frontend, that you can manually use.

If you want your questions answered, then form clear question, that people can answer. If you do not specify the limits, then it is IMO nonprofessional, and at least I will never write a complex solution.

---

Sorry, that my initial answer was not useful for you. I tried to simplify the problem, but I over simplified it. `"Everything should be made as simple as possible, but not simpler." A. Einstein.`

As a potential solution to your problem, I could recommended:

- [Screener](http://www.screenr.com/) - a Java program, that not only streams audio, but also includes screencast video. [image]

If it does not solve your problem, then I hope it's at least useful for you.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear that i want to capture the sound card output of a user and stream it to a server in real time. Usual solutions use something like the Windows Stereo Mix feature, to route the soundcard output to a virtual input. That is a solution I do not want.